# Cannot get SQL Azure Migration Wizard to Connect to SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Trying to use SQLAzureMW to migrate my MSSQL2008 R2 DB to SQL Azure. The script is generated fine, but then I am unable to connect to an existing SQL Azure DB or to create a new Database. I have setup the Azure firewall to accept my IP address. SQL Server Studio Management studio can now access the Azure DB, now that I have sorted the Firewall, but not SQLAzureMW....

Any ideas ..... ?

Is it because I am running SQL Server 2008 R2 and not SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1

Thanks

Comment: Can you add an error message, or exactly where the connection is failing?

Comment: Just sorted it. It was being caused by my own firewall. Thanks for the assist.